# BEGIN...END block in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, iif

Are there any rules defined for grouping the T-SQL statements under the `BEGIN...END` block ?

Because when I try the `BEGIN...END` block inside the `CASE` statement OR `IIF` statement, it fails.

I need `BEGIN...END` block because there are multiple operations that I want to perform under the `CASE` result.

```
SELECT 
CASE @ChargePaid
WHEN 1 THEN 
            BEGIN 
             SELECT 'Paid'
            END
WHEN 0 THEN 
            BEGIN 
             SELECT 'Not Paid'
            END
END
```

OR

```
SELECT IIF( @ChargePaid > 0, BEGIN SELECT 'Paid' END , BEGIN SELECT 'Not Paid' END )
```

**EDIT:**

```
IF @cond = 'First'
WITH CTE AS (
             SELECT 'A missing' Result
             UNION 
             SELECT 'B missing' Result
             UNION 
             SELECT 'C missing' Result
)
SET @msg = SELECT Result from CTE 

IF @cond = 'Second'
WITH CTE AS (
              SELECT 'A missing' Result
              UNION 
              SELECT 'B missing' Result
              UNION 
              SELECT 'C missing' Result
)
SET @msg = SELECT Result from CTE 

IF @ChargePaid = 0
...
Some code goes here to generate the message.
Then I store the actual message into @msg variable.
...

In the end I store the @msg values (I trim the @msg if it requires) to the table.
```

What I want is:

I want to validate the @ChargePaid condition. 
If it comes false, I want to avoid further processing for optimization of code & store charge missing info to @msg variable\table.

Comment: Yes there are rules and no you can't do that. Explain the real underlying requirement not your proposed solution then we can suggest alternatives. c.f. [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - e.g. Why not `SELECT CASE @ChargePaid WHEN 1 THEN  'Paid' WHEN 0 THEN  'Not Paid' END`?

Comment: Aditya, what are you actually trying to achieve. Select case and IIF are not for procedural code. They are for evaluations only. Perhaps you want to do something else? Can you put the problem that you are trying to solve and we can assist with the correct approach.

Comment: @MartinSmith, its just a pseudo code here. Basically it is based on the charge paid condition I will be validating other no. of things and storing the result into the variable to display result=msg on application screen. And in that code I am using CTE so need to write the SELECT immediate after it ... that is why needed BEGIN...END block in this case. I hope you understand?

Comment: Hi Aditya, I see that you want to optimize the code etc in your updated question. It is better to get something working first, then optimize later. Perhaps you can get a working version then ask specific questions about optimization. Your pseudocode is now very different to your original question and still difficult to follow. "IF" statements in TSQL are procedural by the way, as opposed to IIF which is not, so maybe you can use the IF statement to control execution.

Comment: @cameront, anyways, using variables solved my problem. Thanks a lot for the quick help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`BEGIN` / `END`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx) delimit program **statements**.

> Encloses a series of Transact-SQL statements so that a group of Transact-SQL statements can be executed.

[`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) blocks accept **expressions**.

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.

So you are trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: please see edit in question. can you help with that ? + 1