# Many inserts inside a begin-end block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

I have a sql script containing over 150k lines of statements (most of them are inserts). I only want to execute those inserts if the table is empty:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MyTable])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No need to insert data'
    --Stop executing script
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --INSERT #1
    --...
    --Insert #150000
END
```

Problem: it seems like the ELSE block is too large. I tried to use `GO`, but it doesn't work inside BEGIN-END blocks. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BEGIN...END block in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217599/begin-end-block-in-sql-server)

Comment: I would work around by breaking it into two parts: 1st part of script will simply insert your data into a temp table. Then if ` [MyTable]` is empty, you select data from the temp table into your target table.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you! Problem is, that this would require a lot of time to modify all scripts (too much time at the moment). But I'll keep that in mind, if I don't find any other method :)

Comment: Another option would be to create a stored procedure with all the insert statements and simply execute it in the else block.

Comment: No easy way to refactor the code. The best you could do is Use Notepad ++ to do a string replace something like Replace `INSERT`with `\r\nEND\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Nonexistingtable)\r\nBEGIN\r\n    PRINT 'No need to insert data'\r\n    --Stop executing script\r\nEND\r\nELSE\r\nBEGIN\r\nINSERT` . Please make sure the Search mode is Extended in the Replace Tab. You will still have to manually replace Nonexistingtable with the right table. Notepad++ can be used again to assist by searching for Nonexistingtable and clicking "Find all in document" under the find tab. Hope it helps

Comment: @hansmeyer, Please, confirm if my understanding of your query is correct. Are you asking for a mechanism to easily encapsulate all your inserts inside a IF EXISTS logic? If yes then the above comment will help a bit.

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor The begin-end block is too large (contains too much inserts). SQL Server will simply throw weird errors, if I don't add a "GO" statement every 1000 lines. Problem: I can't use "GO" inside a begin-end block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To counter the huge else block, you could use any one the the following 3 strategies.

`STRATEGY 1`

Use Bulk insert from SQL Server. Just dump all your data into a csv file and use the following statement in your else block. Store the csv file on your computer and give it's UNC path after FROM in statement below. This way you will only have a single line in your else block.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.MyTable
FROM '\\share\somepath\myTableInsertData.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

`STRATEGY 2`

Write a stored procedure that inserts only `x` rows at a time. You could then call this stored procedure in a `While loop` and your else block would be very small.  You would call this stored procedure repeatedly in a while loop from your original SQL and then the else block would end being just a few lines of t-sql code.

Note that you can control how many rows are inserted by the stored procedure at a time by using an appropriate value for the variable `@numberOfRowsAtaTime`. I have used 1000 so in a single call of stored procedure 1000 rows get inserted.

Of course, based on your business rules you can script the stored procedure's insert statements. If you have a pattern in your INSERTS then you could script that pattern into the stored procedure logic below.

*Stored Procedure*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertXRows
    @startIndex INT,
    @numberOfRows INT 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @counter INT;
    SET @counter = @startIndex;

    WHILE @counter < (@startIndex + @numberOfRows -1)
    BEGIN 
    -- Insert statements for rows goes here
    --INSERT FOR @counter -- @counter would be different for each iteration
      SET @counter =  @counter + 1;
    END
END
GO
```

*Your SQL*

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MyTable])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No need to insert data'
    --Stop executing script
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    declare @insertRowCounter int;
    set @insertRowCounter = 1;
    declare @numberOfRowsAtaTime int;
    set @numberOfRowsAtaTime = 1000;
    WHILE @insertRowCounter <= 150000
      EXEC dbo.insertXRows @insertRowCounter, @numberOfRowsAtaTime -- insert 1000 rows at a time
      SET @insertRowCounter = @insertRowCounter + @numberOfRowsAtaTime; 
    END
END
```

`STRATEGY 3`

Come up with 10 stored procedures so that each stored procedure has 15000 INSERTS. Then simply call these 10 stored procedures from your else block.

*10 stored procedures*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertProc1
  AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --INSERT1
    --INSERT2

     --INSERT15000

    END
END
GO



CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertProc2
  AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --INSERT15001
    --INSERT15002

     --INSERT3000

    END
END
GO
```

*Your SQL*

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MyTable])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No need to insert data'
    --Stop executing script
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   EXEC insertProc1
   EXEC insertProc2
   EXEC insertProc3
   EXEC insertProc4
   EXEC insertProc5
   EXEC insertProc6
   EXEC insertProc7
   EXEC insertProc8
   EXEC insertProc9
   EXEC insertProc10
END
```

Comment: I'm not a SQL expert, so sorry for this (stupid) question: How would I do this: `--INSERT FOR @counter -- @counter would be different for each iteration`?

Comment: Can you express your INSERT using a pattern? So INSERT1, INSERT2 etc., follow a pattern in the values inserted. If there is a pattern, then I mean that you need to code that logic for INSERT statement when counter is some value like 100 or 101 etc.

Comment: Can you write down the first 10 inserts so I can see if there is a pattern?

Comment: Then you would need a different strategy since you have no pattern. I recommend writing multiple stored procedures like 10. Each procedure will have 15000 inserts. First stored procedure would have INSERT1, INSERT2,....INSERT15000. Second stored procedure would have INSERT15001, ... INSERT30000. And so on. Then just the stored procedures in  your else block like `EXEC insertProc1; EXEC insertProc2; EXEC insertProc3; EXEC insertProc4; EXEC insertProc5; EXEC insertProc6; EXEC insertProc7; EXEC insertProc8; EXEC insertProc9; EXEC insertProc10;`.

Comment: Look at `Strategy 1` or `Strategy 3`. I think `Strategy 1` might be best for you.

Comment: I agree that `STRATEGY 1` should be the best. You can also combine that with a `GOTO`-statement that skips to the end of the script when data exists (thus no inserts are to be made).

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`NOEXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql):

```
create table T (ID int not null)
go
if 1=1
begin
    set noexec on
end
go
insert into T(ID) values (1),(2),(3)
--Repeat more inserts
go
set noexec off
go
select * from T
```

Which just prints an empty table - hopefully you can see how this would be adapted to your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply add this block at the start of your big script, without `else begin ... end` construct?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MyTable])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No need to insert data'
    --Stop executing script and return
    RETURN
END
--Your old script starts here
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this suggestion. I already tried "return", it doesn't seem to exit the script / stop executing the script. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Maybe you have some `GO` inside your script? `GO` is just batch separator form SSMS; it will split script by these and run all parts separately.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `GOTO` statement to jump out of the insertion statements?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MyTable])
BEGIN
    GOTO NODATA
END

--INSERT #1
--...
--Insert #150000

NODATA:
    PRINT 'No need to insert data'
```